# Login to GUI application

Tags: python

I am not familiar with python  and creating user login entry window to login to the another window. The problem is that how can I make sure that it is logged in after entering correct username and password. I could go to the window that I want to login by entering the username and password but I think the coding is still not correct. Another thing is that when the login window pop up, if the user just close the window without entering username and password, the program should just quit. However it still continues to go to the window. Below is my code.

Thank you very much in advance

```
    import Tkinter
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style

class MainWindow(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
            self.parent.title("AUTO TIPS")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)

        lbl = Label(self, text="Status")
        lbl.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        area = Text(self)
        area.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

        abtn = Button(self, text="Drive Command", command=win3)
        abtn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        cbtn = Button(self, text="Tester Manual Control", command=win2)
        cbtn.grid(row=2, column=3, pady=4)

        dbtn = Button(self, text="Auto Run", command=AutoTIPS)
        dbtn.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=4)

        obtn = Button(self, text="OK", command=self.parent.destroy)
        obtn.grid(row=5, column=3)

####################################################################################################################################################        
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

failure_max = 3
passwords = [('Aung', 'Aung')]

def make_entry(parent, caption, width=None, **options):
    tk.Label(parent, text=caption).pack(side=tk.TOP)
    entry = tk.Entry(parent, **options)
    if width:
        entry.config(width=width)
    entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=10, fill=tk.BOTH)
    return entry

def enter(event):
    check_password()

def check_password(failures=[]):
    # Collect 1's for every failure and quit program in case of failure_max failures 
    print(user.get(), password.get())
    if (user.get(), password.get()) in passwords:
        root.destroy()
        print('Logged in')
        return
    failures.append(1)
    if sum(failures) >= failure_max:
        root.destroy()
        raise SystemExit('Unauthorized login attempt')
    else:
        root.title('Try again. Attempt %i/%i' % (sum(failures)+1, failure_max))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x160')
root.title('Enter your information')
#frame for window margin
parent = tk.Frame(root, padx=10, pady=10)
parent.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
#entrys with not shown text
user = make_entry(parent, "User name:", 16, show='')
password = make_entry(parent, "Password:", 16, show="*")
#button to attempt to login
b = tk.Button(parent, borderwidth=4, text="Login", width=10, pady=8, command=check_password)
b.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
password.bind('<Return>', enter)

user.focus_set()

parent.mainloop()        

####################################################################################################################################################              

def win2():

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Tester Manual Control")
    s1Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s2Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s3Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s4Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s5Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s6Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s7Var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    s8Var = Tkinter.StringVar()

    s1Var.set(" Tester 1")
    s2Var.set(" Tester 2")
    s3Var.set(" Tester 3")
    s4Var.set(" Tester 4")
    s5Var.set(" Tester 5")
    s6Var.set(" Tester 6")
    s7Var.set(" Tester 7")
    s8Var.set(" Tester 8")

    square1Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s1Var)
    square1Label.grid(row=1, column=500)
    square2Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s2Var)
    square2Label.grid(row=2, column=500)
    square3Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s3Var)
    square3Label.grid(row=3, column=500)
    square4Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s4Var)
    square4Label.grid(row=4, column=500)
    square5Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s5Var)
    square5Label.grid(row=5, column=500)
    square6Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s6Var)
    square6Label.grid(row=6, column=500)
    square7Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s7Var)
    square7Label.grid(row=7, column=500)
    square8Label = Tkinter.Label(board,textvariable=s8Var)
    square8Label.grid(row=8, column=500)



####################################################################################################################################################

def win3():

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Drive Command")
    codeloadButton = Tkinter.Button(board, text="Code Load", command=win4)
    codeloadButton.grid(row=100, column=50)
    clearButton = Tkinter.Button(board, text="Clear Dos Table", command=win5)
    clearButton.grid(row=500, column=50)

####################################################################################################################################################

def win4():

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Code Load")

####################################################################################################################################################

def win5():

    board = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board.title("Clear Dos Table")

####################################################################################################################################################

def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("350x300+300+300")
  app = MainWindow(root)
  root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you really want to use Tk for a new program? Not gtk or qt?